# How to prevent post update using transition_post_status

Tags: posts, hooks, rest-api, subscription

I am building an application using WP REST API. Ideally, users are able to post only if they have a subscription. Here is how I plan to make things work:

1. Set `expire_by` user meta when they sign up. This key is set to a timestamp 30 days from now. (i.e. users are given a 30 day free trial). I am using `strtotime('+30 days')` to set `expire_by` at the time of sign up.
2. Users can post if current time is less than `expire_by` timestamp. So, I am doing similar to this:

```
if(strtomtime('now')>get_the_author_meta('expire_by', $user_id)){
// let the user post
} else {
// prevent from posting
// show an error 
}
```

3. Inside `subscriptions` page, users are redirected to payment gateway. Once the payment is complete, users' `expire_by` meta key is set to `strtotime('+30 days')`

The problem is step 2. I can't seem to make it work with `transition_post_status` hook. So far, I have tried this:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'check_plan_validity', 11, 3 );
 function check_plan_validity( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
     $expire_by = (int) get_the_author_meta('expire_by', $post->post_author);
     $now = strtotime("now");
     if($now>$expire_by){
         $error['error'] = 'Plan expired';
         echo json_encode($error);
         die();
     }
 }
```

Using the above code gives out a 500 server error on `wp/v2/posts/` routes. My question is how can I prevent the post update *and* show an error on REST routes. I have tried `pre_post_update` hook as well. But no dice. I have also tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325265/prevent-publish-status-date-saved-on-transition-post-status-hook) but the method described there only shows error on admin dashboard. But I want a solution for REST routes.

My logic can be wrong. But I am open to suggestions. Is there any better way I can use to prevent post update/create? I don't want to use any subscription plugin because most of them do not have any support for REST routes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use [`rest_pre_insert_{$post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_insert_this-post_type/) instead of the `transition_post_status` hook. But you should check my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334401).

Comment: The filter you mentioned do not have any access to user's data.

Comment: Well, the callback receives a post data as the first argument, so if the post type supports `author`, then you can use `$post->post_author` to retrieve the user ID, similar to what you've done with the `transition_post_status` filter.

Comment: Nope. That is incorrect. I did a `var_dump($post)` inside `rest_pre_insert_post` and it just contains `title` and `post_content`

Comment: Not 100% "incorrect"... but anyway, the REST API also uses the `wp_insert_post` function which sets the post author to the current user if the `post_author` parameter is not explicitly specified. Therefore you could use `wp_get_current_user()` to access the user data.

Comment: And when *updating a post*, you could use `get_post_field( 'post_author', $post->ID )` to access the *author* of the post. But for the user who actually made the API request (or the user whom authenticated for the API request), then the `wp_get_current_user()` would be the one you should use.